# Issue using <asp:Repeat> to repeat <a> tags, specifically the inner text property

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asprepeater

I'm running ASP.NET 4.0 on VS2013, and I'm having troubles fully understanding the ASP Repeater. 
What I'm trying to do kinda looks like this:

```
<div id="datesDivContainer>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="repeater" DataSourceID="listToAddToHTML">
        <itemTemplate>
            <div>
                <a href=ExistingDate.aspx?Date="+<@#Bind("Date");%>></a>
            </div>
        </itemTemplate>
   <asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Now, what I need is to set the text of the template link tag to the repeater's data source list's item values (the values are dates, e.g. 28/10/2014, therefore the text of the link should be 28/10/2014, 27/10/2014, and whatever other dates the XML file has).

The list is composed out of date elements, and is initialized in the following manner:

```
var list = new List<string>();
XDocument XMLDatesDocument = XDocument.Load("MenuPerDate.xml");
XElement pointer = XMLDatesDocument.Element("menus").Element("menu");
while (pointer != null)
{
    var date = pointer.Element("date").Value;
    if (pointer.ElementsAfterSelf().Count() > 0)
        pointer = pointer.ElementsAfterSelf().ElementAt(0);
    else pointer = null;
    list.Add(date);
}
repeater.DataSource = list;
```

The XML file looks like this:

```
<menus>
    <menu>
        <date>...</date>
    </menu>
</menus>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: I want to set the text of the <a> template to the value of the repeater's data source (the list I explained about earleir).
i.e. for the first item the repeater generates, the text is the first item in the data source list, for the second item generated, the text is the value of the second item of the list, and so on.

Comment: Have you tried to understand the [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)?